# Name of Episodic Style where the opening for next week is the ending of this week

Tags: film-industry

Is there a name for the TV Serial style where the end of each episode is the pre-opening credit intro for the next one?

This style was used on shows such as Quantum Leap. I seem to remember it being quite common but I'm struggling a bit with google-fu because I keep finding people's technical problems with Netflix episode binging.

Comment: 'Cliff-hanger'? This has been used since the 50s or earlier, with Saturday morning matinee movies for kids. Quantum Leap was slightly different in as much as the end of one show was the beginning of the next, rather than it being the end of the current story.

Comment: I assumed there was something more specific for the structure than cliff-hanger. Which I generally associate with stopping in the middle of a two-part story, not simply the break after setting up the story.

Comment: Sure, but as Quantum Leap is the only show I've ever known that uses the last scene to always set up the start of the next episode & has almost nothing to do with the current episode, I'm not sure it has a name.

Comment: @Tetsujin it might be that I'm imagining it being used more widely, but it definitely exists in Sliders as well. I seem to recall it in The Time Tunnel and possibly Land of The Giants.

Comment: There are episodes of The Good Wife that sometimes open with the scene from the last episode, but it might be a different take/audio edit and you never necessarily knew when this was going to happen, meaning that one didn't always realize that it was a cliff hanger ending until the next episode starts with it and makes more or less dramatic, because often times episodes start fresh and takes several episodes to find out the resolution of some dramatic plot or it's dropped altogether...

Comment: The theme here seems to be time travel. Quantum Leap, Sliders, The Time Tunnel, Land of The Giants. *Timeless* tried to do this in a few episodes IIRC. None have done it w/o fail, like QL has AFAIK. The hypernym is *cliffhanger*; specifically *Quantum Leap style*. OH BOY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would contend that the closest technical term for this is "[Cliffhanger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliffhanger)".  From the Wiki:

> A cliffhanger or cliffhanger ending is a plot device in fiction which
> features a main character in a precarious or difficult dilemma or
> confronted with a shocking revelation at the end of an episode[1] or a
> movie of serialized fiction. A cliffhanger is hoped to incentivize the
> audience to return to see how the characters resolve the dilemma.

The point of the cliffhanger is to bring the audience back for the next episode, and in shows like Quantum Leap, it worked pretty effectively.

There isn't really a term for overlapping episodes, it can't really be considered a "[Recap Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recap_sequence)" as the previous episode is mostly inconsequential.

Comment: Outside of TV, such overlaps can be called “elision”, but I agree that the cliffhanger concept is better suited as an answer to the question.